# syncronization of two entity Managers jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have a situation in a web application with JPA where there are two users "normal user" and "admin" . The admin user has the rights to read the information of user and user has the right to update its info. Both have there entity managers. Is it possible in JPA to synchronize the persistence context of these managers so that admin will retrieve the updated value from cache only? Please help.

Comment: In general all caches will be cleared when you start a new transaction and session.  If each admin activity creates a new transaction and session then what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Pace Thanks for the info!! My scinerio is like if two admin users are watching info of normal users and one of them updates the info . User object on the other side become dirty and it will have the dirty info. Is there any way to notify other that object has been changed.

Comment: I don't think you want to merge the two persistence callbacks then.  In that case, it sounds like you would have the following transactions/sessions: 1) Admin A retrieves users 2) Admin B retrieves user 3) Admin A updates user Foo 4) Admin B refreshes user Foo.  In this case each step (number) is a brand new session and a brand new entity manager.  All you would need to do is indicate to the Admin B process that user Foo has changed and Admin B could do a normal find.  If that is the case I might have some ideas but you wouldn't be syncing two persistence contexts/entity managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JPA lifecycle callbacks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) for this (the link is to Hibernate but any JPA provider should off this).  The `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` annotations allow you to do certain activities (e.g. notify other threads) when an entity has been updated.  You can then create a new entity manager on those threads, find the affected entity, and update your display.

Comment: thanks! for a web application how do you notify other sessions of that update?

Comment: That depends on what you are using for your presentation layer.  In general there are no widespread good solutions to this problem yet.  There are a number of not-quite-mainstream solutions (like web sockets) and some more popular but not so pleasant solutions (like polling).  What is your presentation layer?  JSF? Flex? GWT? Something else?

Comment: ,I am using JSF for presentation layer

Comment: You could use this polling solution: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf;jsessionid=673E28D57ED57228B38C4596B6FC9781?c=poll&tab=usage

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a second level cache. l2 cache is conceptually stored in the EntityManagerFactory, so accessible to all EntityManagers.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html